# Email notification with every new article in a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, notifications

i was looking for a way to include some plugin or something like that in my wordpress site. This "plugin" send a mail (to specific contacts) every time i create a new content in my website (event, article, etc..). do you guys know a way to do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to solve this with the publish post action hook - mail to all recipients will be sent on publishing a post. This is how you can achieve it:

```
add_action('publish_post','notify_my_buddies');

function notify_my_buddies($ID, $post ) {

  $recipients = get_option('my_recipients');

  foreach($recipients as $rec) {
    wp_mail($rec,"New Post: ".$post->post_title, "Any content pass here ...");
  }
}
```